# How do I rotate a colour sprite by moving finger along y-axis in the BOTTOM HALF of the screen?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, rotation, location

Code:

```
for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let maxTouchHeight = self.frame.midY

        if currentGameType == .wobble{
            main.zRotation = (location.y)/512
            if location.y > maxTouchHeight { return }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I am trying to rotate a paddle depending on where your finger is on the y-axis in a type of pong game. However, I have been unable to make it so that it only works in the bottom half of the screen i.e. the two extremities of rotation are at the very top and very bottom of the screen but I want the top extremity to be at the top of the bottom half of the screen. (main is a pong paddle).

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Read the Xcode documentation and find out what the zRotation property is.  Nobody knows what 'main' is, but if you want to rotate a node, use SKAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After followed discussion from comments and repeated answer updates, I have a solution for you. Please let me know if questions:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  let paddle = SKSpriteNode()
  let maximumRotation = CGFloat(45)

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    paddle.color = .blue
    paddle.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 15)

    let deg45 = CGFloat(0.785398)
    let degNeg45 = -deg45

    let constraint = [SKConstraint.zRotation(SKRange(lowerLimit: degNeg45, upperLimit: deg45))]
    paddle.constraints = constraint

    addChild(paddle)
  }

  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let location     = touches.first?.location(in: self)         else { return }
    guard let lastLocation = touches.first?.previousLocation(in: self) else { return }
    guard location.y < self.frame.midY                                 else { return }

    // Our vertical plots:
    let yVal  = location.y
    let lastY = lastLocation.y

    // How much we moved in a certain direction this frame:
    let deltaY = yVal - lastY

    // This value represents 100% of a 45deg angle:
    let oneHundredPercent = self.frame.height/2
    assert(oneHundredPercent != 0)

    // The % of 100%Val (45degrees) that we moved (in radians):
    let absY = abs(deltaY)
    let radToDegFactor = CGFloat(0.01745329252)
    let multiplier = (absY / oneHundredPercent) * radToDegFactor

    // I suggest a sensitivity of 2-4:
    let sensitivity = CGFloat(3) 
    let amountToRotate = maximumRotation * (multiplier * sensitivity)

    // Rotate the correct amount in the correct direction:
    if deltaY > 0 {
      // Rotate counter-clockwise:
      paddle.run(.rotate(byAngle: amountToRotate, duration: 0))
    } else {
      // Rotate clockwise:
      paddle.run(.rotate(byAngle: -amountToRotate, duration: 0))
    }
  }
}
```

Just open up a new project and try it out!

There may be an easier way to do this, but this is what popped in my head. It's a little verbose too so hopefully you can see each process step-by-step.

Comment: Thanks dude, but I think that looks a little too complicated to do tonight, as I have to prepare for a German oral, create a presentation showing off the code of this project and complete 2 Design papers tonight haha. But perhaps if I'm up for it in the holiday :) Thank you very much for all the help you've given me though, is there anything I can do like upvoting your profile or something like that?

Comment: @James email me your project: fluidityT@gmail.com i will see if I can implement it for you

I've nothing to do today so :)

Comment: i don't htink you can upvote anything until 15 reputation, so you can come back and do that later XD you can click the checkmark to "accept answer as solution" or whatever it says @james

Comment: I've emailed you the project so have a go if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as doing something using the bottom half only, you can do something like this

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if let touch = touches.first {
        let fingerPosition = touch.location(in: self)
        //this is the bottom
        if fingerPosition.y < self.size.height/2 {
           //just replace print with your own code
            print("bottom half")
        }
        //this is the top half
        if fingerPosition.y > self.size.width/2 {
          //you can just leave this as it is or if ever you want to do something with the top part, just add your own code!
            print("not bottom half")
        }

    }

}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

put this inside of your touches functions:

```
for touch in touches{
  let location = touch.location(in: self)
  let maxTouchHeight = self.frame.midY
  if location.y > maxTouchHeight { return }

  if currentGameType == .wobble{
    main.zRotation = (location.y)/512
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so soon, I have put the code in however I am receiving an error on the part of the code that says: if touch.location.y > maxTouchHeight {return}.    The error says "Ambiguous referance to member 'location(in:)' Any help?

Comment: @James sorry about that, I fixed it. I forgot to add a line :)

Comment: thank you, however that doesn't seem to be the problem as I already had that in my code :/ Any other suggestions?

Comment: @James can you link a screenshot? That code is working fine in my project right now.

Comment: @James or update your question with the full code block.

Comment: @James I'm running your code fine in my project. Are you putting this inside of your `touchesMoved` and `touchesBegan` function? `override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {`

Comment: I just tried building the app again and i no longer get the error, however, it still acts the exact same as before :/

Comment: @james you can still touch the top??

Comment: @James put the `return` if statement above the `.wobble` section.

Comment: Ok, so I can't touch in the top half so thank you very much for that, but unfortunately that doesn't quite solve my problem which is my fault for I assume not explaining correctly.

Comment: When I move my finger up the y-axis a horizontal paddle tilts left or right depending on the y location i.e. titled 45 degrees when a finger is at the top of the screen and -45 degrees when a finger is at the bottom. However, I am trying to change this so that instead of having to move my finger to the very top of the screen it only has to move to the middle of the screen essentially reducing the necessary touch area to the bottom half of the screen. I hope I have now explained this adequately :)

Comment: I understand and apologise for the inconvenience so if you can't be bothered to continue with this I completely understand :)

Comment: @james lol, we're on here to help. solving these problems is fun :P

Comment: @James Ok, I understand your problem now

Comment: Great! Hopefully, it isn't too difficult as I am presenting it tomorrow!

Comment: @James I put a new answer up with an example gamescene.